# How to load a DLL and access its methods

Tags: c++, dll, include

My friend asked me to test a DLL he created, so I figured I would make an Visual Studio 2012 to load in the DLL and run some of the methods he built.  The problem is, I'm not used to including DLL's.

I included my the .h file he gave me, and that loaded properly. I then went into my Project Properties and added the .DLL file to both my Additional Library Directories (under Configuration Properties->Linker->General) and in both the Include Directories and Library Directories (under Configuration Properties->General).

From what I found online, that should have been more than enough to grant me access to his methods.  However, for some reason, my code is still not recognizing any of his custom functions.  Did I miss including something somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding the .lib file to the linker.

Comment: I added the .lib directory to the values in Additional Library Directories, no change.

Comment: It should go in _Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies_ And not the directory, the actual whatever.lib file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for: [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx).

Another way is to use the `LoadLibrary()` function and a supplied header file.